# Matlab stand-alone executables fail to run at first launch but then works

Tags: matlab, crash, executable, launch

I have made a (Windows) installer program that installs the Matlab Compiler Runtime (R2012b) and then, after restart, tries to automatically launch a Matlab stand-alone executable compiled with the same compiler version. I have administrator rights on the computer and the executable is tagged "Run as admininstrator". I have tried this installation procedure on a number of different computer platforms with the following results:

- Win 7 and Win 10 upgraded from Win 7: The executable launces automatically at start-up without issues
- Windows 8 and Win 10 upgraded from Win 8: The executable will most often fail to launch at the first attempt (won't start at all, no code executed) but may work the next. Once it works, it will always work.

This is obviously a problem since my customers, who use arbitrary platforms, are supposed to do this install. If the executable fails at startup, their account is not set up properly and they will not be able to run the installed software. I paid a lot for the Matlab compiler and I really think I could expect a more stable behaviour. Do I need to write something to the Windows registry beforehand, and what? Is there a command line I can add to the executable to force it to run and what should it say?

Your help is greatly apppreciated!

Fredrik

PS. This question has also been posted on Matlab Answers

Comment: Is your msi running in silent mode and suppressing error message output? It sounds like the MCR (Matlab Compiler Runtime) is failing in install somewhere and you aren't catching this.

Comment: I can't exclude that MCR fails. I had a comment about .NET versions. The hardware I'm using together with the executable is compatible with .NET4.0 and 4.5 whereas I was told that MCR 2012b prefers .NET3.5. The hardware drivers are installed before MCR and if no .NET exists, .NET 4.0 is installed. So the MCR installer may fail or become corrupt somehow beause of that. I'm really speculating here.

Comment: Have you tried doing it in 2 stages? IE forcing your customers to install MCR with a non-silent install and then having them run your program rather than compiling everything together as a single executable?

Comment: The easiest way out may be as you suggest - to ask the customer to perform another step rather than to try to understand the root cause of what's going wrong. The risk of errors I probably lower in this case even though I always try to think of my customer's level of computer knowledge to be parallelled by monkeys.

Comment: The alternative would be to package a dozen different versions of the .net framework into your install (thereby bloating your software) so that you cover all the various iterations of your customers PCs..